# Rotate image on BackgroundWorker.DoWork

Tags: wpf, image, rotation, backgroundworker, eventtrigger

I have a background worker which works as desired. But I would like an image in my view to rotate continually from the moment backgroundworker.DoWork is called until backgroundworker.completed is called.

I have tried a little with some event triggers but I can't get it to work. Anny suggestions on how I get on with this?

I use c#, wpf, .Net 4.0, MVVM.

BR

Answer (score 0):

DoWork is not a best place to access UI element, because it is not fired in UI thread, you should use ProgressChanged event

I would suggest to create [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx) and [StoryBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx) for it

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="sbdRotation">
            <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="image"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.LayoutTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
            By="6" Duration="0:0:0.2"
            RepeatBehavior="1x"/>
        </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

...
<Image Name="image" Width="50" Height="50" Source="OK.png">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
```

Inside ProgressChanged event, find StoryBoard with [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx)("sbdRotation"); and call [Begin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190590.aspx)

Comment: Does the FindResources align with the MVVM model?

Comment: But my vackground worker is running from the viewmodel. How can I then access the ProGress changed event from the code behind?

Comment: in that case, I would create a user control, or custom control, that have property progress which is binded to viewmodel property, and will change viewmodel progress from background worker...